# How do I use the conditional WHERE date >= current_date - INTERVAL '{time interval)' using column values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
create table drugs_list (
rule                varchar,
category            varchar,
code                varchar,
code_type           varchar(5),
code_length         int NULL,
look_back_period    int DEFAULT 6
look_back_interval  varchar DEFAULT 'months'
);
```

The table structure looks something like:

| rule | category | code | code type | code length | look back period | look back interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rule 1 | category 1 | xxxxx | hcpcs | 5 | 6 | 'months' |
| rule 2 | category 2 | xxxxx | gpi | 14 | 1 | 'year' |
| rule 3 | category 1 | xxxxx | gpi | 12 | 7 | 'months' |

And so on...

There's another history table I'm working with which looks like:

| sub_id | suffix_id | rule | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | yy | rule 1 | '2020/5/03' |
| yyyy | zz | rule 3 | '2021/01/15' |
| xxxxx | yy | rule 1 | '2020/7/25' |
| xxxxx | yy | rule that is in history table but NOT in drugs_list table | '2020/7/25' |

(Note rows 1, 3, and 4 are the same person. Rows 1 and 3 are the same rule on different days, but rows 3 and 4 are different rules on the same day.. The pattern continues as such with varied combinations for all people)

I don't know the structure of the history table since I didn't create it, but the query I'm trying to run is this:

```
SELECT sub_id,
       suffix_id 
       rule,
       max(date)
FROM history_table ht 
  INNER JOIN drugs_list dl on ht.rule = dl.rule 
WHERE category = (rule category) 
  and date >= current_date - INTERVAL dl.look_back_period || ' ' || dl.look_back_interval
```

The last where condition is supposed to look something like 'and current_date >= INTERVAL '6 months' for the first row in drugs_list table and 'and current_date >= INTERVAL '1 year' for the second row in the drugs_list table

The final table is supposed to look something like this:

| sub_id | suffix_id | rule | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | yy | rule 1 | MAX(date) within the time interval |

The idea is to find information from the last 6 months or last one year, or any other kind of time interval for each
(sub_id || suffix_id) combo by the rule in the rule column (which matches the rule in the drugs_list column) and the MAX value in the date column from history table.

When I try to run the code I get the error:

> [42703] ERROR: column "interval" does not exist

How should I fix this query to get it to work? Could really use some help on this!

(FYI, i originally had the look back period column and look back interval as 1 column VARCHAR DEFAULT '6 months' , but when I tried to run the query that way a parameter window kept popping up)

Comment: Have you tried storing lookback_days as a number. And a filter predicate: date >= current_date - lookback_days

Comment: Why not define a single column `lookup` with the data type `interval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for column based `interval`, here's how you should write it.

```
    SELECT 
        sub_id 
        suffix_id 
        rule 
    max(date) 
    FROM history_table ht 
    INNER JOIN drugs_list dl on ht.rule = dl.rule 
    WHERE category = (rule category) and 
      date >= current_date -  (look_back_period||' '||look_back_interval)::interval
```

try this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=J9FNVxjttO)

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked! I didn't know you could cast as interval like that!